# LINQ aggregate items in a list, concatenate a property

Tags: c#, linq

Please be kind to a LINQ dummy...
Say I have 8 rows data like this:

```
+-------------------+
|  ID   WORKTYPEDESC|
+-------------------+
| 1     plumber     |
| 1     carpenter   |
| 1     electrician |
| 2     juggler     |
| 2     mime        |
| 3     writer      |
| 3     actor       |
+-------------------+
```

As an 8-item `IList<Worktype>` collection where `Worktype` looks like

```
public class Worktype
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string WorktypeDesc { get; set; }
}
```

And what I want is to aggregate by Id to get a list with 3 Worktypes, each with a WorktypeDesc being a sorted, semicolon-delimited list, like this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| ID    WORKTYPEDESC                  |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1     carpenter;electrician;plumber |
| 2     juggler;mime                  |
| 3     actor;writer                  |
+-------------------------------------+
```

??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just group by `Id`, use `string.Join` to aggregate within each group.

```
IEnumerable<Worktype> source = ...;
var query = source.GroupBy(
    x => x.Id,
    (id, g) => new Worktype
    {
        Id = id,
        WorktypeDesc = string.Join(";", g.Select(x => x.WorktypeDesc).OrderBy(x => x))
    });
```

Comment: Voila. The only bit I added was a ToList<Worktype>() to get the type I wanted to return. Thank you!